# Multiple div auto width to fill parent

Tags: css, width

I have a simple question for you guys.

Check the fiddle :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner" style="background: #ff0000;"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background: #00ff00;"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background: #0000ff;"></div>
</div>
```

I can have an unknown number of div inside my container, i need them to fill the parent with exact same width. Without using `display:table-cell;` i need it to be fully compatible with IE7...

Thanks guys !!

http://jsfiddle.net/yaLMk/

Comment: for IE7and less it will be with javascript via script or  expression: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/expression

Comment: I have to fill horizontaly, and verticaly (this part is not a problem). I will probably use jquery to do it.

Comment: yes. you cant achieve this without jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to add jquery to achieve this : [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yaLMk/4/)

```
var containerW = $('.container').width();
var innerCount = $('.container .inner').length;

$('.inner').css({
    width: containerW / innerCount
});
```